# Static resource management: is it feasible to combine resources upon request?

Tags: css, http, static-resource

What are the performance differences between the following three, assuming they work in a semantic manner:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="one.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="two.css" />
```

and:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="oneandtwo.css" />
```

and:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="combine.php?combine=one,two" />
```

Is there any major disadvantage to combining resources upon request, from a server load and user latency standpoint?

Comment: Of course it causes additional server load to do processing on the fly, but you can offset that by caching the result…